# Defining 60hz refresh rate on 4K monitor with xrandr

Tags: linux-mint, xrandr

I recently bought 
[BL3201PT](http://www.benq.com/product/monitor/bl3201pt/specifications/) which is capable of delivering 4K@60Hz. I connected it with DP. The output from `xrandr` shows the following:

```
$ xrandr -v
xrandr program version       1.4.1
Server reports RandR version 1.4
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.1*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
...
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160      30.0  
   2560x1440      60.0  
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9  
   ....
```

Its telling me it is only 30Hz. I have tried to define a newmode but it gives me error.

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  59
  Current serial number in output stream:  59
```

Graphics cards:

```
$ lspci  | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
14:35:53 ~ 
$
```

Using mint 17. Any hints?

Update: BTW, I have a dual boot on the machine and in the second OS (Windows) the refresh rate is 60Hz as it should be.

Output of `dpkg -l | grep xfont`:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep xfont
ii  libxfont1:amd64                                                      1:1.4.7-1ubuntu0.2                                  amd64        X11 font rasterisation library
ii  xfonts-base                                                          1:1.0.3                                             all          standard fonts for X
ii  xfonts-encodings                                                     1:1.0.4-1ubuntu1                                    all          Encodings for X.Org fonts
ii  xfonts-mathml                                                        6ubuntu1                                            all          Type1 Symbol font for MathML
ii  xfonts-scalable                                                      1:1.0.3-1                                           all          scalable fonts for X
ii  xfonts-utils                                                         1:7.7+1                                             amd64        X Window System font utility programs
```

Some extra info:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia 
ii  nvidia-settings                                                      370.28-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1                          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
10:37:23 ~ 
$ lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2211]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] [10de:11fc] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2211]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
10:37:32 ~ 
$
```

Comment: It's possible that the *graphics card* isn't capable of delivering 4K@60Hz, because the dot clock is limited, or because the driver has the wrong limits. Check `Xorg.log` to see why this mode is rejected.

Comment: `Kernel driver in use: nouveau` Yeah that isn't going to work. You need to install the correct drivers as per my instructions.

Comment: Again: Look into `Xorg.log` to see *why* this particular mode is rejected. If you have the nouveau driver and the limits ("dot clock too high, mode rejected") for your card are wrong, contact the developers and let them fix it.

Answer (score 2):

What is your graphics card and graphics driver version? When I was having trouble with getting 4k to work on Linux on my GTX 770, I simply added the `xorg-edgers` PPA with the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and installed the latest Nvidia drivers, after which I was able to simply select the proper display options from the GUI. So, I recommend that you try to update your graphics drivers before trying anything else.

EDIT: To be more specific, you use the command `sudo apt install nvidia-current` to install the latest Nvidia drivers, or you can use `apt search nvidia-` and `sudo apt install nvidia-XXX` to install a specific version of the driver.

Additionally, do NOT go to Nvidia's website to install drivers!

Comment: $ lspci  | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
14:35:53 ~ 
$

Comment: updated the question with info about the graphics card.

Comment: what do you mean "from the GUI". Where in the GUI? I use xrandr to configure my display.

Comment: In Ubuntu I can just search Display and then edit the settings from there. I assume Mint has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

create a mode:

```
xrandr --newmode "10x10" 60  20 20 20 20  10 10 10 10  -HSync +Vsync
```

add the mode:

```
xrandr --addmode DP1 10x10
```

ps... "BadName" = you already have something with that name, trash it or give it another name. for example:

```
xrandr --newmode "10x10_bob1" 60  20 20 20 20  10 10 10 10  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --newmode "10x10_bob2" 60  20 20 20 20  10 10 10 10  -HSync +Vsync
```

is fine...

Comment: I have tried defining a newmode, it did not help.

Comment: please post `dpkg -l | grep xfont`

Comment: @Bahamut posted the output in the question.

Comment: @user11498, i see when you tried xrandr you got the error "BadName", this is because you used a name that already existed.

Comment: I dont have mint, but I miss 2 packages in your output. `sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi`

Comment: @Bahamut I installed but no any new progress. Mint is based on ubuntu.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` and `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2` gives more Information about your hardware.  Any /etc/X11/xorg.conf?

Comment: @Bahamut updated the question. No /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

Comment: According by my search on nvidia, you need nvidia-version 367.57

Comment: Sorry doppelcomment. Im too slow. So Aaron franke gives you the correct advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47759/discussion-between-bahamut-and-user11498).